# What is the Credential Implementation needed to Revoke refresh tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, google-iam

### Question:

What is the Credential Implementation needed to Revoke refresh tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK

---

### Scenario

I have a cloud function that executes the following code:

**CloudFunctionCode:**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
try { admin.initializeApp() } catch (e) { console.log(e) }

//...Irrelevant code in between...

function getRevokeRefreshTokens(request, response) {
  try { admin.initializeApp() } catch (e) { console.log(e) }
  admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens('Oe4IXqqZj1b1fsfPYFjft0tebs11')
    .then(() => {
      return admin.auth().getUser('Oe4IXqqZj1b1fsfPYFjft0tebs11');
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      return new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime() / 1000;
    })
    .then((timestamp) => {
      console.log("Tokens revoked at: ", timestamp);
      return response.status(200).send(
        "Tokens revoked at: ", timestamp
      )
  });
}
```

**Log Error from Cloud Function:**

```
Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property has insufficient permission to access the requested resource. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for details on how to authenticate this SDK with appropriate permissions.
    at FirebaseAuthError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:143:16)
    at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:182:16)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:818:49
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

**Current IAM Member with roles:**

[image]

After reading the [Manage User Sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens) docs on how to Revoke refresh tokens I could not find exactly what Credentials I need for the firebase-admin so that it is allowed to revoke refresh Tokens.

Comment: You shouldn't try to catch errors from initializeApp, nor should you call it more than once per process.  If it fails, you simply should not continue to execute - everything will be broken all the time, and you need to fix your function.

Comment: Which roles are assigned to PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com - unless you have changed the service account assigned to the function.

Comment: I believe the service account tied to your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS key file needs the [Firebase Auth Admin role](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-product#auth).